# Atualizacao e publicação de aplicativo android privadamente

Tags: android

Tenho a necessidade de **publicar um aplicativo de forma privada**, onde só quem tem o endereço ou liberação possa fazer **download e atualizações via appstore**, é possível controlar dessa forma a aplicação?

Consigo ao menos fazer atualização automática de um aplicativo sem precisar copiar para o celular e instalar por cima da versão antiga?

Comment: tem como sim, já realizei alguns testes em app publicado, informei meu e-mail ao desenvolvedor ele me colocou como beta tester, tente pesquisar sobre isso, ou espere um pouco alguém aqui com certeza saberá :) ... Seja bem vindo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma forma de você criar um grupo de testers, onde somente eles podem receber o aplicativo, mediante a convite, veja [este exemplo](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) do google, para testar em primeira mao seus apps em formato beta.

Nesta [página oficinal do google(ptbr)](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=pt-BR) ensina como criar um grupo de testers, basta seguir as orientações da página.

Caso tenha dúvidas, esta página abaixo tem um passo-a-passo tambem, mas na pagina oficinal do google é mais que suficiente.

http://wcabralti.blogspot.com.br/2014/06/android-beta-testing-no-google-play.html